# How to use parameters in a specific input in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

There are some paremeters and a specific input in matlab that I use with another software.

The problem is, when these codes run I need to see '10 20 30' for `a` in workspace. Is it possible?

```
x1=10
x2=20
x3=30

a='x1 x2 x3'
```

This is what I'd like to see:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to see a string (as per the answers below) or a matrix containing those three values? The latter is simply `a=[x1 x2 x3]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = sprintf('%i %i %i', x1, x2, x3);
```

You should use string interpolation if possible for this, as it is much cleaner than all the `strcats` and `num2strs`.

Comment: Hugh. I wonder why I always forget about `sprintf`. Must be because I rarely use long strings in Octave/Matlab anyway. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
a='x1 x2 x3'
```

you declare `a` as the string "x1 x2 x3", which has absolutely nothing to do with the variables `x1`, `x2` or `x3`.

What you should do if you want the values of thoses variables to show up, is to convert these into a string. A quick and dirty way to do this is

```
strcat(strcat(strcat(strcat(num2str(x1),"\t"),num2str(x2)),"\t"),num2str(x3))
```

Of course, it is a lot cleaner if you encapsulate this in some sort of function. But before you do that, I recomment that you read a basic tutorial to get a good grasp of types.

Comment: Up vote for the explanation, but I don't agree with your suggestion for converting to a string. I think that is the most roundabout way possible!

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks and I agree :) My point was actually to tell OP that he needs to learn about types. Not knowing about them would make his life much harder when he has a matrix of uint8 when he wants floating point values. I think string formatting is arguably the least of your worries when working with Matlab/Octave, so I didn't put much thought into that line of code.